# BCryptGenRandom STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows, bcrypt, mingw-w64

I am trying to generate cryptographically secure numbers in Windows. I have the following code:

```
#ifndef w64crypt
#define w64crypt
#include <windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>
unsigned long getSeed(ULONG buffer_size){ 
    NTSTATUS status=0;
    ULONG flags=0;
    PUCHAR c_seed;
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE handle;
    status=BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
            &handle,BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM,NULL,0
    );
    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)){
            cout << "BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider";
            printf("%X",status);
    }
    status=BCryptGenRandom(
            handle,c_seed,128,0
    );
    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)){
            cout << "Error in BCryptGenRandom";
            printf("%X",status);
    }
    status=BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(
            handle,0
    );
    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)){
            cout << "BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider";
            printf("%X",status);
    }
    unsigned long seedNo=(unsigned long)c_seed;
    return seedNo;
}
#endif
```

When I run this, I get `Error in BCryptGenRandom C0000008`, which is `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`. This is what the documentation calls for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptopenalgorithmprovider

```
NTSTATUS BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
  BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE *phAlgorithm,
  LPCWSTR           pszAlgId,
  LPCWSTR           pszImplementation,
  ULONG             dwFlags
);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom

```
NTSTATUS BCryptGenRandom(
  BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm,
  PUCHAR            pbBuffer,
  ULONG             cbBuffer,
  ULONG             dwFlags
);
```

The above link also states that `pszAlgId` must be:

> The handle of an algorithm provider created by using the BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider function. The algorithm that was specified when the provider was created must support the random number generator interface.

Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-algorithm-identifiers, `BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM` is my ideal candidate.

I'm compiling this using `mingw-w64`, cross-compiling from Ubuntu 18.04.

Why am I receiving this `NTSTATUS`?

Comment: `c_seed` is pointing to an indeterminate value, so all bets are off when it is passed to `BCryptGenRandom` with the claim that it points to 128 bytes to be written to. My guess would be that it's clobbering `handle` inside the function as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that I'm late, but hopefully this helps people who're having the same issue.

The documentation doesn't mention it, but you can use one of the predefined pseudo-handles for common algorithms. Here's an example

```
unsigned int GenAESKey(char* keyb) {
NTSTATUS s;
/*BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE algh;
s = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&algh, BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM, MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER, 0);
if (s != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    return (unsigned int)s;*/
s = BCryptGenRandom(BCRYPT_RNG_ALG_HANDLE, (PUCHAR)keyb, CABINET_AES_KEY_S, 0);
if (s != STATUS_SUCCESS)
    return (unsigned int)s;
return 0;
```

You can see the list of all the predefined pseudo-handles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-algorithm-pseudo-handles)

Comment: I'm going to have to revisit this - I got the answer a while ago. Hold on a minute.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me:

```
unsigned long getSeed(int size){
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE handle;
    int Buffer;
    PUCHAR bPointer=(PUCHAR)&Buffer;
    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
            &handle,BCRYPT_RNG_ALGORITHM,NULL,0
    ))){
            std::cout << "BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider failure\n";
    }
    NTSTATUS status=BCRYPT_SUCCESS(BCryptGenRandom(
            &handle,bPointer,sizeof(Buffer),0
    ));
    if(!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)){
            printf("%X",status);
            std::cout << "Error in BCryptGenRandom";
    }
    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(
            handle,0
    );
    return static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(bPointer));
}
```

The original code claiming that the buffer was 128 bytes in it's call to `BCryptGenRandom`, which wasn't true. The buffer in the original code called `c_seed` was a wild pointer, most likely with size 8.

In this case, `c_seed`, now aliased as `bPointer`, is no longer wild - it is pointing to `int Buffer`. The size of this buffer is being passed to the function using the `sizeof` macro, so though likely that it is size 8, it can accommodate whatever target architecture the cross-compiler I was using needs.

Comment: It would be good if you described what 'this' is that solved it for you.

Comment: Look at the comments in the question - I was claiming that the buffer was 128 bytes, which wasn't true. The buffer, then called `c_seed` was a wild pointer, most likely with size 8.

Comment: In this case, `c_seed`, now aliased as `bPointer`, is no longer wild - it is pointing to `int Buffer`. The size of this buffer is being passed to the function using the `sizeof` macro, so though likely that it is size 8, it can accommodate whatever target architecture the cross-compiler I was using needs.

Comment: As for the `&` in the new answer vice the old one? I'm not sure. I haven't messed with this code base in over a year, I posted this to *hopefully* close the loop on this question. Maybe in another year, I'll have this project back up and running :)

Comment: I really think you ought to consider editing all of that into the answer. It's a good explanation.